# Check if String Array contains a Substring without loop

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I want to find a substring in an array of strings, without using loop. I'm using:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] files = new String[]{"Audit_20190204_061439.csv","anotherFile"};
        String substring= ".csv";

        if(!Arrays.stream(files).anyMatch(substring::contains)) {
            System.out.println("Not found:" + substring);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm always getting Not found. What is wrong with the approach?

Comment: You are just **hiding** the loop via the stream. That doesn't make the approach any better not faster than a straightforward, understandable, `for` loop.

Comment: On the contrary, see how the overuse of lambdas caused you to make a mistake that is hard to find (wrong parameter order in the substring function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking whether the `String` ".csv" does not contain any of the elements of your `Stream`, which is the opposite of what you wanted.

It should be:

```
if (!Arrays.stream(files).anyMatch(s -> s.contains(substring))) {
    System.out.println("Not found:" + substring);
}
```

P.S. As commented, you can use `noneMatch` instead of `anyMatch`, which will save the need to negate the condition:

```
if (Arrays.stream(files).noneMatch(s -> s.contains(substring))) {
    System.out.println("Not found:" + substring);
}
```

and if the ".csv" substring should only be searched for in the end of the `String` (i.e. treated as a suffix), you should use `endsWith` instead of `contains`.

Comment: `!` + `anyMatch()` -> `noneMatch()`

Comment: The OP probably wants to use `String#endWith` here, since `.csv` is an extension, should only appear at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You possibly need to check the file extension and can use `endsWith` for it instead and improve your condition to:

```
if (Arrays.stream(files).noneMatch(a -> a.endsWith(substring))) {
    System.out.println("Not found:" + substring);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a streams guru, but I believe that you want something like this:

```
String[] files = new String[] { "Audit_20190204_061439.csv", "anotherFile" };

for (String file : files) {
    if (file.endsWith(".csv")) {
        System.out.println("found a CSV file");
    }
}
```

I use `String#endsWith` here because presumably `.csv` refers to a file extension, and should only register a hit if occur at the end of the filename.

We could also use `String#matches` here:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\.csv$");
for (String file : files) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("found a CSV file");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend against `file#matches()` inside loops, better create a `Pattern` beforehand: `Pattern.compile(".*.csv$")`

Comment: @Lino And in fact you have told me this before.  I guess old habits die hard :-(